# AWS MFA does not work with Authy desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, two-factor-authentication

I have authy installed on Ubuntu 20.04.2.  On my IAM user page I click on the Manage link and Virtual MFA device.  I copy the secret key.  In Authy I click + to add an account and copy the secret key from AWS.  I click Add Account, choose a title and select AWS and leave the token length set to 6.  When I submit AWS gives an error showing Invalid MFA device.

Is there something more I need to do to get MFA with Authy and AWS?

Comment: AWS supports [Authy](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/features/mfa/?audit=2019q1).  How positive are you that your Ubuntu is set to the correct time? At any point in the process does it indicate what the correct code should be, so you know the Authy, is generating the correct code?  I am familiar with MFA, Authy, just not AWS.  That doesn't matter since TOTP is universal.   I assume you have actually clicked on `Assign MFA`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried again after dinner at it just worked.  Must have been something temporary on AWS.

Not much of an answer, but authy's been working.

Comment: Authy works fine with AWS. When I have problems it's usually user error.